# Showing that the language of graphs and nodes on an odd cycle is in NL

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, space-complexity

> Let L be the language containing all the pairs (G,v) where G is a directed graph and v is a vertex in G such that G contains a cycle that contains v and the number of different vertices that appear in that cycle is odd. Find the smallest class (NP, P or NL) that contains L.

Clearly L is in NP, I didn't manage to show that it is in P so I tried to show that it's NP-Complete, however the answer in the textbook is NL?

Comment: And what exactly is your question? What have you tried and where did you get stuck, in detail?

Comment: I have tried to show that the language is in NL, but I didn't find a correct solution. I don't think that there is a need to describe solutions that I know that are incorrect.

Comment: Just to be sure: if there is a sequence $u_1\dots u_{k-1}u_ku_{k-1}\dots u_1$ where each vertex has an arc to the following one, does that count as a cycle?

Comment: I believe that it should be counted as a cycle.

Comment: So, let us call $(s,t,n)$-connectivity the problem of deciding whether there exists a path of length exactly $n$ from $s$ to $t$ in the input. This problem is in $\mathsf{NL}$ (the proof is very much like the proof that $(s,t)$-connectivity is in $\mathsf{NL}$). Then wouldn't the following solve the problem? Guess a node $u$ in the graph, then for each odd number $1\leq k\leq n$, and each decomposition $k=k_1+k_2$ into two integers, solve the problems of $(v,u,k_1)$-connectivity and $(u,v,k_2)$-connectivity? I can elaborate in an answer if you don't detect any bug in this.

Comment: What do you mean by "path of length exactly $n$"? if $n$ is the number of edges then you have found a cycle that contains an odd number of edges, but how do you know if there is a cycle that contains an odd number of different vertices?

Comment: In the first line of my comment, $n$ denotes any positive integer, not the size of the graph. Anyway, I didn't see that the oddness property was on the number of different vertices, thanks for catching this.

Comment: Do you mean simple cycle or a closed walk?

Comment: Closed walk $ $

Comment: Does anyone know of a NP-complete problem that is similar to $L$?

Comment: @rosebud convert to answer?

Comment: @RanG.: the reduction in my comment is wrong, I misunderstood the statement of the initial problem!

Comment: @rosebud oh, I misunderstood it as well (it is a bit ambiguous). But it seems that for **NL** it should be interpreted as a path of odd length. Otherwise, can't we reduce Hamiltonian cycle to it (doubling the nodes, so any non-Hamiltonian cycle would have to have even number of nodes)?

Comment: @RanG.: I don't see it, sorry. Wouldn't any closed walk have an even number of nodes in this context? Plus the problem here is about closed walks and not simple cycles, I'm not sure I understand how your reduction works.

Answer (score 1):

The question is ambiguous. Specifically, it is not clear what "different vertices that appear in that cycle" means. It can mean two things (1) the size of the set of nodes that appear in the path, or (2) the total number of nodes in that path, i.e., the length of that cycle (minus 1).

If the interpretation is (2), then the language is clearly NL:
you perform a random walk (of length $\le n$), counting the number of nodes you see. If you get back to $v$ and the number of nodes is odd, you accept, otherwise you reject.

If the interpretation is (1), I don't see an immediate way to show it is in NL.